# Is it possible to read 4,500,000,000 as four thousand five hundred million?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, grammatical-number, numbers

Is it possible to read 4,500,000,000 as four thousand five hundred million?

I know the number is four billion five hundred million, but wonder if there is another option.

Comment: That would be a suboptimal confusing way of speaking the number for an AmE audience. They would think they'd misheard. Seowjooheng Singapore's answer "Four point five billion" is the norm in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are no non-zero digits after the first two, we could simply read it as *four point five billion*.

Reading it as *four thousand five hundred million* should be possible but is likely to be less common.  Words like *trillion, billion* and similar are there to ease speech and writing and should be used where it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible and in older varieties of British English that used the "billion = million million" convention, this would be the standard reading.  You won't find that convention used much now, as the French/US convention is now standard in most style guides, including the BBC.